# Could not load file or assembly CefSharp.Core.Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

I used NuGet Package Manager to install https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Which added the item to my `.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.WindowsDesktop">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
    <UseWPF>true</UseWPF>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="CefSharp.Wpf" Version="87.1.132"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Next I modified my xaml file to look like this:

```xml
<Window x:Class="csharp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:csharp"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:CefSharp.Wpf;assembly=CefSharp.Wpf"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="webBrowser" Address="http://localhost:4200">
        </wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Lastly, I added the following constructor in the `App.xaml.cs` file:

```cs
namespace csharp {
  public partial class App : Application {
    public App() {
      var settings = new CefSettings() { // Line 12
        CachePath = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData), "CefSharp\\Cache")
      };

      settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-media-stream");
      settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("use-fake-ui-for-media-stream");
      settings.CefCommandLineArgs.Add("enable-usermedia-screen-capturing");

      var dependencyCheck = true;

      Cef.Initialize(settings, performDependencyCheck: dependencyCheck, browserProcessHandler: null);
    }
  }
}
```

When I run the application, I am getting the following error:

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/System.BadImageFormatException
An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in CefSharp.Wpf.dll: 'Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.Runtime, Version=87.1.132.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=40c4b6fc221f4138'. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.'
   at CefSharp.CefSettingsBase..ctor()
   at CefSharp.Wpf.CefSettings..ctor()
   at csharp.App..ctor() in App.xaml.cs:line 12
   at csharp.App.Main()
```

[image: Files]

Why could it not load the package?

**Edit:**

Here is the new file structure after updating:

[image: New file structure]

Answer (score 0):

Is it using the correct dll? My initial guess is that there is a mismatch between the Program architecture and the used CefSharp.Core.dll, e.g. the program runs in 64 bit mode but references the 32bit assembly.

Comment: How would I figure that out? I am new to WPF and C# configurations.

Answer (score 0):

Can you upgrade to netcoreapp3.1? If yes then switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.Wpf.NETCore/ should resolve the problem.

The Badimageformatexception is rather misleading in the context of loading a C++/CLI assembly, any failure will give this exception. See https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/31743#issuecomment-582168696 for background.

If you need to stay with netcoreapp3.0 then you'll need to either specify a PlatformTarget or a RuntimeIdentifier in your project file.

Comment: I was able to update and I still couldn't run the app, as I get the same error.

Comment: I added an image to show the new structure. I am still getting `BadImageFormatException` though...

Comment: Can you close visual studio,  delete the bin and obj folders and start from a fresh build.

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/3284#issuecomment-772132523 for details on specifying a RuntimeIdentifier.

Comment: I got it working, I had to set `RuntimeIdentifier`, and I also had to change my launch target file which I was forgetting.